# Beautify code with php code beautifier not working

Tags: php, php-beautifier

I am trying to beautify my code through code beautifier. So I typed -

```
sudo phpcbf -n --standard=PEAR filename.php
```

Its showing me phpcbf command not found. Then I tried to install phpcbf using 
the command-

```
sudo pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/php_beautifier-0.1.15
```

And the output is -

> pear/php_beautifier is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.1.15
>   install failed

why that happens? I can't find any helpful resource to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `which phpcbf`. If it shows anything, it means that it's installed; it it doesn't, it means you need to add the install location to the `PATH`.

`tino.codes` is correct, but if you need to use the command `phpcbf`, you can always add an alias to `php_beautifier`. Open up your `~/.bash_profile` and add the following line:

```
alias phpcbf='php_beautifier'
```

then, save that file and run `source ~/.bash_profile`.

And now you have an alias to a, then, non-existent command.

Answer (score 0):

[phpcbf](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) is not Pear package you have installed.

The [Pear package](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/docs/PHP_Beautifier/tutorial_PHP_Beautifier.howtouse.commandline.pkg.html) command is `php_beautifier`: